# Python Click options - Avoid taking multiple times the same option if the parameter multiple is not passed

Tags: python, python-click

I am using python click for my development purposes. I have the following command line with one option:

`add student -n xx -n yy`

code :

```
@click.group()
@click.version_option("Development", help="Echo version and exit")
@click.help_option(help = "Use this on subcommands for more information")
def cli():
    '''Add a student/teacher/principal'''

@cli.command()
@click.option('--name', '-n', required=True, help='Specify the name of the student')
def student(name):
    '''Add a Student'''
```

While using the above command line, how I am able to use the same option multiple times?? I see that the value for `name` is `yy`. How can I avoid taking multiple `-n` if multiple is not true??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple with a tweak. Make the `multiple=True`. Accept the multiple values. And throw error if there are more than one item.

```
def check_multiple(ctx, param, value):
    if len(name) > 1:
        click.echo('Multiple options are not accepted!')
        ctx.abort()
@cli.command()
@click.option('--name', '-n', required=True, multiple=True, callback=check_multiple, help='Specify the name of the student')
def student(name):
    ''' '''
```

Since, I don't have a current setup, the above code is not tested; Derived from the [documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/).

Comment: That sounds like an option but for every option I cannot do the same. There can be n number of options and I have to add extra two lines for that.

Comment: Either you need to do it multiple times, or define a callback function which will check this for each option or wait for a better answer.

Comment: this again is a function which will be invoked every time even if the value for the option is not specified.

Comment: Whatever checking you are expecting, from library or callback, it has to execute some check internally anyhow.

Comment: Yeah. I did not wanted to handle that. I wanted click to handle that.

Comment: It is an OpenSource Code. If you want, you can contribute to the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Use the kwargs

```
multiple=True
```

Running this

```
import click


@click.group()
@click.version_option("Development", help="Echo version and exit")
@click.help_option(help="Use this on subcommands for more information")
def cli():
    """Add a student/teacher/principal"""


def validate_student(ctx, param, value):
    try:
        if len(value) > 1:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return value
    except ValueError:
        raise click.BadParameter('Students should be not more than 1')


@cli.command()
@click.option('--name', '-n', required=True, multiple=True, help='Specify the name of the student',
              callback=validate_student)
def student(name):
    """Add a Student"""
    print(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    student()
```

Gives me this

```
$ python3 add.py -n xx -n yy
    Usage: add.py [OPTIONS]

Error: Invalid value for "--name" / "-n": Students should be not more than 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But passing only 1 param returns:

```
$ python3 add.py -n xx
('xx',)
```

This is documented here: http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#multi-value-options and here http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#callbacks-for-validation

Comment: I do not want multiple values. click should take multiple -n only if multiple=True, otherwise it should not allow the user passing multiple -n rather than taking the last value.  I have updated the question.

Comment: The answer was perfect before your question was edited.

Comment: then check if len(tuple) > 1 and handle it